# r: convert trial and error calibration to automated

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the following `data.frames`

```
#df is data.frame to be used to get the simulated values
df <- read.csv(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1jyrxlinyql0d8/df_simu2.csv?raw=1"))
head(df)
#     ID loss      area param1 param2
#1 well5 8.62 0.3430550   High   High
#2 well5 8.62 0.1643353   High   High
#3 well5 8.62 4.2321602   High   High
#4 well5 8.62 0.0349235 Medium   High
#5 well5 8.62 0.0648697 Medium   High
#6 well5 8.62 0.0444421 Medium   High

#df_measured is the data.frame that have the measured values to be compared with the simulated values later
df_measured <- read.csv(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/77v6ysdi1ziqq6i/df_measured.csv?raw=1"))
head(df_measured)
#     ID measured
#1 well1  29.7513
#2 well2  21.7710
#3 well3 191.6334
#4 well4 260.2431
#5 well5 532.3491
```

and this code to get the simulated values and compare them with measured values

```
library(dplyr)
df_simulated <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(loss1 = loss / 1e3,                                               #convert the units 
                param1_no = ifelse(param1 == "High", 0.7,                         #convert param1 values to numbers
                                    ifelse(param1 == "Medium", 0.5, 
                                           ifelse(param1 == "Low", 0.3, NA))),
                param2_no = ifelse(param2 == "High", 0.9,                         #convert param2 values to numbers
                                        ifelse(param2 == "Medium", 0.5, 
                                               ifelse(param2 == "Low", 0.3, NA)))) %>%  
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(simulated = sum( loss1 * area *  (1- param1_no) * (1 - param2_no), na.rm =T)) %>% 
  #merge it with df_measured to comapre simulated with measured
  dplyr::full_join(., df_measured, by = "ID") %>%                                 
  dplyr::select(ID, simulated, measured)
```

I got this result

```
#df_simulated
# A tibble: 5 × 3
#      ID simulated measured
#  <fctr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1  well1 115.90577  29.7513
#2  well2  31.68084  21.7710
#3  well3 299.77588 191.6334
#4  well4 387.15474 260.2431
#5  well5 519.88316 532.3491
```

The `simulated` values are not close to the `measured`values except in `well5`.
In order to get the `simulated` values as close as possible to the `measured`, I need to change the values for the levels of `param1_no` and `param2_no`

For both `param1_no` and 'param2_no'

1. `high` can vary from 0.67 to 0.99
2. `medium` can vary from 0.34 to 0.66
3. `low` can vary from 0.01 to 0.33

During calibration, I can keep changing these values manually "trial and error" till I get the `simulated` values as close as possible to the `measured` ones.

However, doing this manually is time taking. 
I will highly appreciate if you could suggest any faster way to get the best set of values for (`high`, `medium` and `low`) for `param1_no` and `param2_no` that bring the simulated values closer to the measured ones.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `hydromad()` Package and the `SCEoptim` function in there? You can feed your formula and the parameter limits into the optimizer and it returns calibrated parameter values (according to a objective function you have to define) [Link](http://hydromad.catchment.org/#SCEoptim)

Btw: The title of the question isnt that good...

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I haven't checked it yet.

Comment: Any suggestions to improve the title?